# Delaying a single task in a Timer

Tags: java, android, timer

I am using a `Timer` to regularly schedule a task, which works fine:

```
t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new CheckTask(), 0, Defaults.CHECK_INTERVAL);
```

Now, in the `run()` of the `CheckTask` I would like to change the interval once. Is that possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cancel the first task and reschedule again

```
t.cancel();
t = new MyTimerTask();
t.schedule(t, yournewdelay);
```

From the Docs

> "Cancels the Timer and all scheduled tasks. If there is a currently
>   running task it is not affected. No more tasks may be scheduled on
>   this Timer. Subsequent calls do nothing."
>
> You'll need to initialize a new Timer when you are rescheduling.

Comment: creating a new timer is unecessary! just call "cancel" and then "schedule"!

Comment: @haywire If you don't initialize a new one you'll get this error :Exception errorjava.lang.IllegalStateException: TimerTask is scheduled already

Comment: Thanks. My solution was a bit different (I use a counter to skip a few processings), but your answer was the answer to the question.